# Single versus double quotation marks in HTML & CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-webfonts

Could anyone clarify the difference between single and double quotation marks in HTML5 & CSS.

Here's Google's contradictory use of single quotes in HTML:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And CSS:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

While Bootstrap's documentation practices demonstrate the use of double quoted marks in HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

And CSS:

```
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

Which practice is the **best** and **why** ?

EDIT:
Is there any *valid reason* why Google Fonts decided to use single quotes ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Either are valid, but you probably should stick to a certain style guide. For example, [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/) suggest using [double quotes for HTML](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=HTML_Quotation_Marks#HTML_Quotation_Marks) and [single quotes for CSS](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=CSS_Quotation_Marks#CSS_Quotation_Marks). (Although Google Fonts doesn't follow this exactly)

Comment: Exactly, I'm quite disturbed by Google's Fonts single quote usage.

Comment: @vorststoom, would you say you feel ...a disturbance in the fonts? Sorry, couldn't help myself :)

Answer (score 9):

There's no best practice, because neither has any affect at all on how the code is parsed. You can deliminate attributes and other strings using `'` or `"` interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no difference. They are interchangeable.

The only important note is not to use one inside itself.

For example in php:

```
echo '"hello world"';
```

Outputs - "hello world"

Or

```
echo "'hello world'";
```

Outputs 'hello world'

BUT

```
echo ""hello world"";
```

Will throw an error if the " is unescaped, as it's closing that parameter before the contents.

Comment: Unrelated to the OP.

Comment: This is Relevant and Important.