# what is the difference between single quotation ' and double quotation " on CSS?

Tags: css, frontend, web-frontend

in url I use single quotation,

```
@font-face{
    font-family:gotham;
    src: url('fonts/gotham-bold.otf') format('otf'),
         url('fonts/gotham-light.otf') format('otf');
}
```

and here I use double quotation,

```
@font-face{
    font-family:gotham;
    src: url("fonts/gotham-bold.otf") format("otf"),
         url("fonts/gotham-light.otf") format("otf");
}
```

What difference are these code process?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697934/single-versus-double-quotation-marks-in-html-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks can be included within the attribute value when the value is delimited by double quote marks, and vice versa. Authors may also use numeric character references to represent double quotes (") and single quotes ('). For double quotes authors can also use the character entity reference "

**So,it seems to be no difference. Only depends on your style.**